# php - how to make thumbnail of video with out ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm using php ( Phalcon frameWork ) .

I tried to using ffmpeg to do this but its taking too much .

I need a thumbnail as screen shot from video .

Is there any other solutions ( Only PHP ) ?

this is my code :

```
    // where ffmpeg is located, such as /usr/sbin/ffmpeg
    $ffmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';

    // the input video file
    $video  = BASE_PATH . "/public/uploads/video/" . $fileName;

    // where you'll save the image
    $image  = BASE_PATH . "/public/uploads/image/" . "thumbnail-".$fileName .".jpg";

    // default time to get the image
    $second = 1;

    // get the duration and a random place within that
    $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video 2>&1";
    if (preg_match('/Duration: ((\d+):(\d+):(\d+))/s', `$cmd`, $time)) {
        $total = ($time[2] * 3600) + ($time[3] * 60) + $time[4];
        $second = rand(1, ($total - 1));
    }

    // get the screenshot
    $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss $second -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $image 2>&1";
    `$cmd`;
```

Comment: @user3783243 i added my codes in topic . You're right but its taking too much .

Comment: @user3783243 no its working fine without any error . its generating thumbnail successfully . but in a long time ( About two mitune )

Comment: Oh, so you're looking for better performance, not just something that can get the job done. That's important to add. How large is the file? You've verified the time lag is at `\`$cmd\``?